# JavaScript вопрос Intl.DateTimeFormat странно выводит секунды

Tags: javascript

```
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    second: '2-digit'
  })
```

ожидалось, что секунды будут выводиться в формате 01 02 03, но вместо этого выводятся 1 2 3, при чем когда я вывожу не только секунды, а и минуты

```
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit'
  })
```

то результат как и ожидалось будет 00:00, при чем есть еще одна особенность, если значение ключа указать 'numeric' то результат будет такой же

```
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric'
  })
```

выведет 00:00, хотя ожидается 0:0 - это нормальная работа этого конструктора и на что вообще должны влиять 'numeric' и '2-digit'?

и всё-таки есть способ вывести одни секунды в формате 00 с помощью Intl?

Answer (score 2):

Тут, насколько я смог разобраться в [стандарте](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#sec-12), вырисовывается следующая картина. Стандарт говорит, что элементы внутреннего свойства `[[localeData]]`, соответствующие поддерживаемым локалям, должны содержать свойство `formats`, в котором перечислены все поддерживаемые комбинации опций, с соответствующими значениями этих опций. Конструктор при вызове ищет в этом списке комбинацию, наиболее близко соответствующую переданным опциям, и применяет именно найденные свойства.

Судя по всему в `[[localeData]]['en']` хранится что-то таком духе: `[..., {seconds : 'decimal'}, ...]`, и нет ничего более близкого к передаваемому `{seconds : '2-digit'}`. Что-то аналогичное происходит и во втором случае, когда передается `{minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric'}`. Находится только `{minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}`, и в итоге применяются именно эти опции.

Результат можно наблюдать при помощи метода `resolvedOptions()`:

```js
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
  second: '2-digit'    
}).resolvedOptions());
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
  minute: 'numeric',   
  second: 'numeric'    
}).resolvedOptions());
```

Мораль такова: использовать произвольные сочетания опций форматирования нельзя, а можно только определенные их комбинации. К сожалению, не знаю, где посмотреть доступные варианты, и есть ли среди локалей такая, в которой предусмотрено использование {`second : '2-digit'}`.